# enqueue a linked list - java

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

For an assignment (thats due pretty soon), I have to enqueue a linked list that I have implemented by hand (not using java's built in class). The linked list is as follows:

```
public class SnocList {
    private char c;
    private SnocList l;

    public SnocList(){
    }
    public SnocList (char x, SnocList y) {
        this.c = x;
        this.l = y;
    }
    public char getC(){
        return this.c;
    }
    public SnocList getL(){
        return this.l;
    }
    public void setNext(SnocList input){
        this.l = input;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (this.c == 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

my Queue class is as follows:

```
public class SnocQueue {
    private SnocList list;

    public SnocQueue(){
        this.list = new SnocList();
    }

    public void enqueue(char c){
        //I don't know what to put here
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to do this. It's apparently pretty simple but I don't know how to do it. for those of you that want to help, enqueue will add a new node to the list where the null reference (null pointer) of the previous list was.

[ 'a' | --]-->[ 'b' | --]-->[ 'c' | null ]     add new node here

Answer (score 0):

To enqueue you need a 'tail' field and a 'head' field too, for this example I will make a queue of objects of a class 'Item', you can use the nodes you need

```
public class Item {
    private int value;
    private Item next;

    public Item(int val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    public void setNext(Item item) {
        this.next = item;
    }
}
```

And the Queue:

```
public class SomeQueue {
    private Item head;
    private Item tail;
    private int size;//size is used to verify if it has Items and avoid null references

    public SomeQueue(){
        this.size = 0;
    }
    public void enqueue(Item item) {
        if (this.size > 0) {
            this.tail.setNext(item);
            this.tail = item;
        } else { //this is when the size is 0, it means is empty
            this.head = item;
            this.tail = item;
         }
        this.size++;
    }
}
```

As you see the important things for your queue are the head and the tail, the method setNext is important too, to make reference between the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a SnocList head node - this is the first 
   SnocList node in the Linked List.
2. Create enqueue method
3. In enqueue method, first check if head SnocList is 
   empty (or == null). If so, just make the head 
   SnocList a new SnocList that contains your passed-in character and the reference to the `l` SnocList. 
   `l` would be `null` because there would be no other 
   SnocLists in the linked list. Then, `return` to end execution of the method.
4. If head exists (`else`), traverse the linked list using a while loop until you hit a SnocList whose reference to `l` is `null`.
5. Append a new SnocList to the end of the linked list by assigning a new SnocList object `new SnocList(ch, curr.l)` to the previously null `curr.l`.

   ```
   public class SnocQueue {
    SnocList head;

    public void enqueue(char ch) {
         if(head == null) {
            head = new SnocList(ch, null);
            return;
         } else {
            SnocList curr = head;
            while (curr.l != null) {
                curr = curr.l;
            }
            curr.l = new SnocList(ch, curr.l);
         }
    }
   }
   ```